# why does NOT the ubuntu 13.10 have the version.h?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, kernel

`/usr/src/linux-header-3.11.0.12`
`/usr/src/linux-header-3.11.0.12-generic`

Neither has the version.h file in the `/include/linux/`. Why?

That hinders the softwares installation.

Comment: first things I do with a new ubuntu build is to install the build-essential and kernel headers packages. Note however that it is considered a security risk to have compilers and compilation resources installed on public facing servers, so exercise appropriate caution.

Comment: @FrankThomas Care to elaborate on how a compiler is a security risk? Because I don’t see how that could possibly be the case.

Comment: Because they allow an attacker who compromised a low-privledge account to compile attack code locally. This is usually prerequisite to performing an escalation of privileges, and taking root. for instance this CVE describes one set of vulnerabilities that requires compilation to exploit: https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/cve_2013_2224_denial_of . and another: http://www.calculate-linux.org/glsa/show/201009-03 both these escalation attacks required that the attacker compile on the system under attack. Its the most surefire way to make sure exploit code runs on all systems.

Comment: To ubuntu , the kernel headers are installed in the /usr/src by default, I confirm, and for the ubuntu 11.10, I find the version.h in the proper place in the generic folder. –

Comment: @FrankThomas This does not mean installing a compiler is a security risk. An attacker would most likely provide their own compiler. If someone managed to gain access to an installed compiler, it’s already too late on so many levels that it simply doesn’t make a difference anymore.

Comment: Security is never perfect, and thus Depth of defense stratagies are necessary to make the attacker struggle for every inch of ground. It has long been accepted that public facing production servers should not have compilers or development tools installed for this reason. It is of course up to you as to whether you find the precaution reasonable. many many people do.

Answer (score 4):

By default, kernel headers are not installed. This is because they are not necessary for software from Ubuntu’s official repositories. They are required only for compiling kernel modules, which is not what the average user does.

Instructions on how to install them, taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/268710):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

`/usr/include/linux/version.h` is part of the `linux-libc-dev` package. It is part of the default Ubuntu installation.

Comment: I tried , It download the 3.11.0.22 version of headers and also the generic , there is no version.h in both of them.

Comment: @user252098 True, but that’s to be expected. Its location is `/usr/include/linux/kernel.h` after all.

Comment: In English please, preferably whole sentences. If you can’t put your problem into words, we can’t help you.

Comment: sorry , I just can't understand that why you mention the kernel.h ?  does it has any relationship with the version.h ?

Comment: Thank U , I see the version.h under the /usr/include/linux/  , but how to use it ?

Comment: To ubuntu , the kernel headers are installed in the /usr/src by default, I confirm,  for the ubuntu 11.10, I find the version.h in the  proper place in the generic folder.

Comment: Eh, just a mistake, sorry. I meant `version.h`, of course. This is the default location for this file on just about any modern Linux distribution. Since it’s in `/usr/include`, `#include <linux/version.h>` is enough. If you’re having a more specific problem, I suggest you open a new question and explain it there in greater detail, with error messages and the like.